# PayPal Credit Card Transaction Error: Payment Failed. System error. Please try again later

Tags: android, cordova, paypal, ionic2, paypal-mobile-sdk

**General information**

- SDK/Library version: 3.5.0
- Environment: Sandbox
- PayPal-Debug-ID values:
- Platforms: Android Device OS Version and Device: Android 7 on
  Nexus 5X (Emulator)
- Issue description

I have tested my app using the Pay With Card option with the test credit card number 5555555555554444 with CCV 123 & Expiry date: 12/20 from PayPal Test Credit Card Number By Google Search.

It shows **Payment Failed: System error. Please try again later.** sometimes:
[Paypal Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzPlt.png)

But, when I checked the PayPal Business test account in the PayPal sandbox dashboard, **the transaction is charged and is shown as completed** like this:
[Paypal Sandbox Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIweZ.png)

Sometimes it works normally, sometimes it doesn't and show me this error, what is the cause of this problem? Is there a fix or a quick hack to bypass it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I am getting error is because I was using the credit card number from [this table](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm). These credit card numbers are overused and PayPal team did not provide us with a better error response.

It was a known issue in **PayPal-Cordova-Plugin** GitHub repository. The solution is to **generate the credit card number from [this generator](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1413)**.